# React Asynchronous nested data fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, nested, fetch

I tried to fetch names for each of "characters" from https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/ and then show it on page but my page render without nested fetch data.
As first Im fetching data from https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/ and then i mapping "characters" value, its array of urls and making axios for each of them, result push to array, when I console.log(array) array after it Im getting "value below was evaluated just now", when I JSON.stringify(array) console show me nothing
[image]

My code:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        let array = [];
        axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/`)
        .then(firstData=>{ 
            Promise.all(
                firstData.data["characters"].map(url=>{
                    axios.get(url)
                    .then(character=>{
                        array.push(character.data.name);
                    })
                })
            ).then(result=>{
                console.log("array:",array);
                JSON.stringify(array);
                })
        })
    } catch (err ) {
        // errors
        console.log(err,"connection error")
    }
} 

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't waiting for all of your promises to resolve before logging the array, the main issue is that you don't return the promise from your map function, you could do:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        let array = [];
        const firstData = await axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/`)
        await Promise.all(
            firstData.data["characters"].map(url=>{
                return axios.get(url).then(character=>{
                    array.push(character.data.name);
                })
            })
        ).then(result=>{
            console.log("array:",array);
            JSON.stringify(array);
        })
    } catch (err ) {
        // errors
        console.log(err,"connection error")
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you, maybe you can  tell problem at my  main  question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125026/how-to-wait-for-evaluating-values-in-react-from-nested-requests  There I tried to fetch main data then fetch automatically data from arrays but  data from additional requests not showing